# Cppunit testing ONLY returns Ok(0)

Tags: c++, cppunit

I'm currently doing cppunit testing on my project. The 2 functions checkWord and checkFile both return 'true' bool values when I compile and run the program normally. Then when I use these 2 functions for my cppunit testing. The output result will always be OK(0). Instead of the OK(1) I should be seeing when i run either of the CPPUNIT_ASSERT().
Anyone can help me with this?

Below are my codes for the project:

checkWord function

```
bool ScrambleWordGame::checkWord(string checkWord) {
ifstream file("WordDatabase.txt");
vector <string> wordList;

copy(istream_iterator<string>(file),
     istream_iterator<string>(),
     back_inserter(wordList));   
file.close();    

if(find(wordList.begin(),wordList.end(),checkWord) != wordList.end())
    return true;
else 
    return false;
}
```

checkFile function

```
bool ScrambleWordGame::checkFile(string filename) {
ifstream file(filename.c_str());
if(file)
    return true;
else 
    return false;
file.close();
}
```

SWGTest.cpp

```
#include "ScrambleWordGameTest.h"
#include "ScrambleWordGame.h"

void ScrambleWordGameTest::testEquals() {
  CPPUNIT_ASSERT(swg.checkFile("WordDatabase.dat"));
//CPPUNIT_ASSERT(swg.checkWord("cat"));
}
```

Comment: You will never reach the `file.close()` statement in your function.

Comment: maybe it's failing to open "WordDatabase.dat"?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Y is that? Is it because of my if-else condition?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Then what abt my checkWord function? Is the if-else condition wrong too?

Comment: As greatwolf pointed out, it probably can't open the file. Maybe your test is run with a different working directory than you expected, and so it can't find the file in that directory

Comment: @jalf Hmmm. My other functions seem to work just based on that file name. This is weird....

Comment: What do you mean by `Ok(0)` and `Ok(1)`? The functions just return a bool (`true` or `false)`)

Comment: Well, welcome to the fun, fun world of debugging then. :) Once you've written a test that fails, the interesting part is figuring out *why*.

Comment: @jalf Yes the functions return a bool. When I call the function using `CPPUNIT_ASSERT()` Then the cppunit is supposed to return me a value based on the result of the function, which in this case returns a true value. Then the output should be OK (1) instead of OK (0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Registration for the test case is missing. Therefore, the following line is needed in the testclassname.cpp

```
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION (testclassname);
```